# which method should I add?

Tags: android-studio

I'm new to android studio. I have problem with syncing my project with this title "android studio “Gradle project sync failed. Basic functionality (e.g. editing, debugging) will not work properly”.

error message:

> Gradle DSL method not found :'mavenCentral()'
>   Possible causes:
>   .The project may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
>   .The built file may be missing a gradle plugin.

Comment: Did you update Android studio recently ?

Comment: No, I don't. I'm using android studio version 1.2.2

Comment: I had maven related issues after update. But I tried Invalidate and reset option in the studio and solved. Please try File->Invalidate Caches/Restart. Not sure on this.

Comment: I added these  "mavenCenteral(), mavenLocal()" to my gradle file of project synced it. but after that I added some changes in build.gradle module file of my project. after that I can't sync my gradle. even I added maven plugin bud it didn't work too .

Comment: Ok, I am not seeing mavenCentral in my projects. Instead, it is jcenter. Please check this link for info on this. http://blog.bintray.com/2015/02/09/android-studio-migration-from-maven-central-to-jcenter/